# Adding lines using CGRect

Tags: ios, swift

I can draw two perpendicular lines using UIView. I make **y** in vertical line 0, but if I change **y** I will not get perpendicular lines. How can I improve code?

```
var scanlineRect = CGRect.zero
var scanlineStartY: CGFloat = 30
var scanlineStopY: CGFloat = 0
var topBottomMargin: CGFloat = 30
var scanLine: UIView = UIView()

var scanlineRect2 = CGRect.zero
var scanlineStartY2: CGFloat = 100
var scanlineStopY2: CGFloat = 0
var topBottomMargin2: CGFloat = 30
var scanLine2: UIView = UIView()
func drawLine(Rect: CGRect) {
    if Rect == scanlineRect
    {
        self.view.addSubview(scanLine)
        scanLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        scanlineRect = CGRect(x: 15, y: self.view.frame.height/2, width: self.view.frame.width - 30, height: 5)
        scanLine.frame  = scanlineRect
        scanLine.center = CGPoint(x: scanLine.center.x, y: self.view.frame.height/2)
        scanLine.isHidden = false
    }
   else if Rect == scanlineRect2{
        self.view.addSubview(scanLine2)
        scanLine2.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        scanlineRect2 = CGRect(x: 350, y: 0, width: 5, height: self.view.frame.height/2)
        scanLine2.frame  = scanlineRect2
        scanLine2.center = CGPoint(x: 350, y: scanLine2.center.y)
        scanLine2.isHidden = false
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    drawLine(Rect: scanlineRect)
    drawLine(Rect: scanlineRect2)
}
```

When **y** of vertical line equals 0

[image]

When **y** of vertical line is **NOT** equals 0

[image]

Comment: You ask how to improve the code but you don't say exactly what you are trying to do or how you would like it to be improved.

Comment: @ColGraff I need to get perpendicular lines even if vertical line's **y** is not equals to 0.